# How to use a recursive query in a subquery in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I created a recursive query that returns me a string of the productcategory history (typical parent-child relation:

```
with recursive productCategoryHierarchy as (

  --start with the "anchor" row
  select
    1 as "level",
    pg1.id,
    pg1.title,
    pg1.parentproductgroup_id
  from product_group pg1
  where
    pg1.id = '17e949b6-85b3-4c87-8f76-ad1e61ea01e1' --parameterize me

  union all
  -- Get child nodes
  select
    pch.level +1 as "level",
    pg2.id,
    pg2.title,
    pg2.parentproductgroup_id

  from product_group pg2
  join productCategoryHierarchy pch on pch.parentproductgroup_id = pg2.id

)

-- Get hierarchy as string
select
  CONCAT('',string_agg(productCategoryHierarchy.title, ' > '),'')
from productCategoryHierarchy;
```

Now I want to **use this result in another query as a subquery** so that I can use the created string as an attribute in the parent query. Is that possible in Postgres or is there another solution to get a hierarchical tree as string in an attribute?

Comment: The `concat()` seems useless as you are essentially appending only empty strings to the result of the string_agg.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
with recursive productcategoryhierarchy as (
...
), aggregated_values as ( 
  select string_agg(productCategoryHierarchy.title, ' > ') as all_titles
  from productCategoryHierarchy
)
select ..., (select all_titles from aggregated_values) as all_titles
from ... your main query goes here ..
```

Comment: Don´t think so.... I have a query that gets a list of all products. And each product belongs to a specific category. And in this product query I want to get a column with the complete category hierarchy (e.g. "Food > Drinks > Beer").